# C++ Type Conversion during Arithmetic Operation

Tags: c++, c++11, math, types

I am new to programming and learning C++ using C++ Primer Plus, 6th Ed. by Stephen Prata.

In Chapter 3, it states that

> "when an operation involves two types, the smaller is converted to the larger."

The example it provides is from a previous listing where `9.0/5` (`double` divided by `int`) results in a value of `1.8` (`double`). It states that `5` is converted to `double` before doing the division. Hence, a `double` divided by a `double` will result in a value that is also `double`. This makes sense.

However, if this is the case, why is it that `10.0 / 5` (`double` divided by `int`) results in 2 (`int`). Should not the answer be `2.0` (if `5` is converted to `double` and then divided into `10.0`)?

Comment: What makes you think 10.0 / 5 gives an integer result ? It doesn't.

Comment: um… The result of `10.0 / 5` is of type `double`. It definitely is. It's also `2.0` if you print it appropriately. Is this just a printing issue maybe?

Comment: Also consider using a [better book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks! I looked at various reviews and think I will start on C++ Primer. However, I will still use some of the problems from C++ Primer Plus, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you print a double with .0, the output is just the integer part. You can test it by compiling this code:

```
double num = 2.0;
std::cout << num;
```

Output will be: `2`

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was wanting an answer to!

Comment: Note that you can change the way std::cout prints doubles and make it print `2.0`. You can use std::setprecision(int), however std::cout is not the only way to print something.

Comment: @Michael are you suggesting to use `printf()`? this is no longer C++, though.

Comment: @Walter no I didn't. qDebug() should print doubles as `2.0` for debugging purposes but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

> "when an operation involves two types, the smaller is converted to the larger."

The book's citation doesn't refer to the **values** of the types used in an operation, but their **size**.